# Process and update simultaneously bunches of data.frames/matrix in R

Tags: r

I have bunches of data.frames in R workspace. And I have exactly same processing to treat them. Since I am "lazy" to run the command for each data.frame one by one, I wish to treat them as a group and process them with a loop which saves time.

Let me say, simply,  to apply `as.data.frame` to those matrix for example of my real serial data-processing.

```
# dummy data
set.seed(1026)
a<-matrix(rnorm(100),50,2)
b<-matrix(rnorm(100),50,2)
c<-matrix(rnorm(100),50,2)
# process data one-by-one which is not good
a<-as.data.frame(a)
b<-as.data.frame(b)
c<-as.data.frame(c)
```

I could do but it is time-consume. I turn to a lazy but quick way similar to`*apply`dealing with rows or columns inside data.frame.

`sapply(c(a,b,c),as.data.frame)` or `sapply(list(a,b,c),as.data.frame)`, or even:

```
> for (dt in c(a,b,c)){
+ dt<-as.data.frame(dt)
+ }
```

But, none of them make changes happened to the original three matrix.

```
> class(a)
[1] "matrix"
> class(b)
[1] "matrix"
> class(c)
[1] "matrix"
```

I wish to see all of them have been trans to data.frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using `sapply`, which simplifies results to `vectors` or `matrices`.

You want `lapply` instead:

```
lapply(list(a,b,c), as.data.frame)
```

**Edit** for the (generally frowned upon) practice of changing the objects systematically but keeping the object names the same:

```
for(i in c("a", "b", "c"))
    assign(i, as.data.frame(get(i))
```

Comment: Thanks, but my `a`,`b`,`c` are still `matrix` format. I wish to make changes happened to all of them after loop (*apply or for).

Comment: `data_list_after_processing<-lapply(list(a,b,c), as.data.frame);a<-data_list_after_processing[[1]];b<-data_list_after_processing[[2]];c<-data_list_after_processing[[3]]` If so, it happens, but this not "lazy" enough.

Comment: You want to still be able to call them by `a` `b` and `c`? That's generally bad practice in R, but it's possible. I'll edit.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I want to know about. I just know `get()` but did not know `assign` yet.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you a list of 3 `data.frames`:

```
set.seed(1026)
lapply(1:3,function(x){as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100),50,2))})
```

Comment: This generates data.frames - I think OP wanted to convert them. `matrix(rnorm(...))` was just dummy data.

Comment: Thank you, but just like @SeñorO said, that's dummy data, and I have added more texts to show what I want.